# how to execute update

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Can someone help me here with my little Java/MySQL Database tool?
Part of the code is as follows, but when clicking on the *createCustomerButton* the DBMS tells me, that my syntax is somehow wrong.

```
protected static JTextField nachnameField = new JTextField();
protected static JTextField vornameField = new JTextField();
protected static JTextField postleitzahlField = new JTextField();
protected static JTextField strasseField = new JTextField();
protected static JTextField emailField = new JTextField();
protected static JTextField telefonField = new JTextField();
protected static JTextField zusatzinfoField = new JTextField();
static JButton createCustomerButton = new JButton("Kunde anlegen");
```

...

```
public static void passStatement(String statementString)
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(statementString);
    preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

...

```
public class Listener extends Main implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    if (me.getSource() == createCustomerButton) {
        nachnameField.getText();
        vornameField.getText();
        strasseField.getText();
        postleitzahlField.getText();
        telefonField.getText();
        emailField.getText();
        zusatzinfoField.getText();
        String statement = "INSERT INTO kunde (nachname, vorname, strasse, 
        postleitzahl, telefon, email, zusatzinfo) VALUES("+nachnameField+","
        +vornameField+","+strasseField+","+postleitzahlField+","+telefonField+","
        +emailField+","+zusatzinfoField+")";

            try {
                passStatement(statement);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                createLowerPanel();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
}
```

Full error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near'
[,322,4,461x19,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,
alignment' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance
(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance
(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2840)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
at Main.passStatement(Main.java:66)
at Listener.mouseClicked(Listener.java:46)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6508)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3311)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile -- You've got a method nested within another method?!

Comment: @Reimeus OP updated ;) sry

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels These are just PARTS of the code. These are the lines I recently changed coursing the error. before that it was running fine. And no, there is no method in another method, sinco it wont compile then, like you said ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a string value that you are inputting to a SQL database then you need to put single quotes before and after each element e.g..

```
tring statement = "INSERT INTO kunde (nachname, vorname, strasse, 
    postleitzahl, telefon, email, zusatzinfo) VALUES('" + nachname + "','" // use variable here
    + vorname + "')"; // ...... etc...
```

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getText()` on your JTextFields and just ignoring the String returned. Instead your passing the actual JTextField's toString result and not its text into your SQL statement. Don't do that.

So instead, get the text Strings from your fields, and put them into String **variables**. Then use those variables to build your SQL statement. i.e.,

```
String foo = fooTextField.getText();
// now use foo, not fooTextField to create your SQL statements.
```

i.e.,

```
if (me.getSource() == createCustomerButton) {
    String nachname = nachnameField.getText(); // get text put into variable
    String vorname = vornameField.getText();

    // .... etc

    String statement = "INSERT INTO kunde (nachname, vorname, strasse, 
    postleitzahl, telefon, email, zusatzinfo) VALUES(" + nachname + "," // use variable here
    + vorname + "," ...... etc...
```

---

Also:

- Learn and then use PreparedStatements as these are safer to use.
- Don't add MouseListeners to JButtons as this will lead to bad button behavior (i.e., disabled buttons that still work, buttons that don't respond to space bar presses...)
- Use ActionListeners instead.
- Don't overuse static modifier as you're doing. Using them in this way suggests that your code needs to be improved greatly.
- Don't post bad snippets as you're doing as that will only confuse us.

Comment: Just tried that, but it doesn't make any differenc - same error :/

Comment: @sehams: you have to do this with ***all*** the JTextFields, not just the one I've shown.

Comment: I know. :D I did change all of them.
I also got rid of the MouseListener handling my buttons and now use a PreparedStatement for my query.

Comment: Also thanks for all the advices. I'm quite a novice to coding and an absolute newbie to object oriented programming.

Comment: sadly no. could it be the static modifiers? Is there any other way for the class Listener to get the JTextField strings created from a method in another Class?